# Is there a way to call XSLT user-defined function by name?

Tags: xslt

Assume I have several user defined functions

```
    <xsl:function name="f:functionA" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="object"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'a'"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="f:functionB" as="xs:string">
      <xsl:param name="object"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'b'"/>
    </xsl:function>
```

This functions do similar actions with little difference. The question is: can I call this functions by name, stored in some variable for example?

```
<xsl:var name="handlerName" select="f:getHandler($element)"/>
<xsl:value-of select="invoke-by-name($handlerName, $param1, $param2, 'param3')"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in XSLT/XPath 3.0 with e.g. `function-lookup(xs:QName('f:functionA'), 1)('foo')` which would find the function named `f:functionA` with arity `1` (i.e. having one parameter) and call it with the string `foo` as the argument.

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-function-lookup for the definition of `function-lookup` in XSLT/XPath/XQuery 3.0.

A complete example using two functions is

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:f="http://example.com/f"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math f"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:function name="f:functionA" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="object"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="'A: ' || $object"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:function name="f:functionB" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="object"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="'B: ' || $object"/>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template name="main">
        <xsl:value-of select="function-lookup(xs:QName('f:functionA'), 1)('foo'), function-lookup(xs:QName('f:functionB'), 1)('bar')"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and outputs `A: foo B: bar`.

In XSLT 2.0 you would need to follow the approach described by Dimitre Novatchev in http://edu.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/EC/lehre/sommersemester-2011/funktionale-programmierung/folien-und-materialien/Higher-Order%20Functional%20Programming%20with%20XSLT%202.0%20and%20FXSL.pdf, it shows how to write higher order functions in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: In fact in 3.0 rather than storing the name of the function in a variable, it's better to store the function itself in a variable: `<xsl:variable name="f" select="if ($condition) then f:functionA#1 else f:functionB#1"/><xsl:value-of select="$f('foo')"/>`

Comment: @MichaelKay, I agree, but `f:getHandler($element)` looked like selecting the name from some input element so I thought using `function-lookup` might be needed.